# Preserving location privacy

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis, zero-knowledge-proofs, secret-sharing

What are cryptographic techniques that could be used so that if I wanna to enable a server to send message to certain nodes in a network with preserving the privacy location for them ??

Comment: well you seem to think it can be done by elliptic curves and/or secret sharing and / or zero knowledge. could you share your thoughts and make a better stated question?

Comment: Well... If Google for "privacy preserving location", you wil get a ton to read...

Comment: What kind of "certain" condition are you interested in? An interactive proof exists to verify that distance is less than (or more than) some known radius. Is interaction with nodes allowed?